# why css/js pagination not showing on this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I copied and made my page according to this link: [link to css pagination](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Stylish-jQuery-Pagination-Plugin-simple-Pagination.html)
and here is my html markup according to instructions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pagination</title>
 <link href="simplePagination.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
<script>
$('#light-pagination').pagination({
items: 1, 
itemsOnPage: 1, 
pages:20, 
displayedPages:5, 
edges:2.  
currentPage: 1, 
hrefTextSuffix: "#page-",
hrefTextSuffix: '',
prevText: "Prev", 
nextText: "Next", 
cssStyle: "light-theme", 
selectOnClick: true,
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="light-pagination" class="pagination"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But my page displays nothing! What am I missing? Please help.

> EDIT:

html markup image :[all html markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGfzN.png)

Comment: Always post your code as text; never as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error `edges:2.`. Learn to use developers tool

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#light-pagination').pagination({
    items: 1, 
    itemsOnPage: 1, 
    pages:20, 
    displayedPages:5, 
    edges:2,  
    currentPage: 1, 
    hrefTextSuffix: "#page-",
    hrefTextSuffix: '',
    prevText: "Prev", 
    nextText: "Next", 
    cssStyle: "light-theme", 
    selectOnClick: true,
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Stylish-jQuery-Pagination-Plugin-simple-Pagination/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Stylish-jQuery-Pagination-Plugin-simple-Pagination/simplePagination.css">


<div id="light-pagination" class="pagination"></div>
```

Comment: i have uploaded the image (under edit) and made changes as your code sujjests.

please help, beginner here.

Comment: @AshishUpadhyay put your script after the `light-pagination` container. Sorry I didn't noticed immediately it's on the head section or wrap your script with `$(document).ready()`. Current implementation will not work since when the script is loaded, your div is not yet ready or not yet available from the DOM

Comment: can u send me a working html file?codepen or something?

Comment: thanksssss it worked finally! :) i really like stackoverflow community!

Comment: @AshishUpadhyay you're welcome! happy to help! SO is your friend :)